# Powershell array sort and separate into two different array

Tags: arrays, powershell, sort-object

I have this array :

```
[

"org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail-123-Email",
"org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"
]
```

And want to sort it out and make two seperate arrays like this one

```
[
"org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail-123-Email",
"org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo"
]


[
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"
]
```

Hoping for your help! Thanks :)

Comment: Along with some of the answers below, you may want to use the following regex to group by unique values.  `Group-Object -Property @{E={$_ -replace '[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)-.8', '$1'}}` to group by `123`/`joemarmoto`, or `E={$_ -replace '([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)-.8', '$1'}` to group by all but the final field name.

Answer (score 1):

Simple array filtering:

```
$arr="org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail-123-Email",
"org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"

$arr2 = $arr.where{$PSItem -match 'joemarmoto'}
$arr3 = $arr.where{$PSItem -notmatch 'joemarmoto'}
```

Answer (score 1):

a somewhat different method would be to use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group on a calculated property. you did not specify the exact part to sort on - the dummy email or the name that comes after it - so i used the part after the dummy email.

the result gives you a collection of arrays with a name [the calculated property] and a group [the items that matched that calculated property]. you can address them individually OR use them to make new arrays.

```
$AllNames = @(
    'org-dummyemail-123-AccountName',
    'org-dummyemail-123-Email',
    'org-dummyemail-123-PAT',
    'org-dummyemail-123-PATName',
    'org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo'
    'org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName',
    'org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email',
    'org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT',
    'org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName',
    'org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo'
    )

# 3rd item index = 2
$PartToGroupOn = 2

$GroupedAllNames = $AllNames |
    Group-Object -Property {$_.Split('-')[$PartToGroupOn]}

$GroupedAllNames[1].Group
```

output ...

```
org-dummyemail-123-AccountName
org-dummyemail-123-Email
org-dummyemail-123-PAT
org-dummyemail-123-PATName
org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo
```

Comment: what if it will become multiple arrays can this also be applied?

Comment: @art-a-game - i don't understand your question. [*blush*] could you try to restate it?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. What if I dont know how many groups I will have I wont be able to hard code the number in this part "$GroupedAllNames[1].Group"

Comment: @art-a-game - ah! well, you don't need to know the number. take a look at the content of the `$GroupedAllNames` variable. one of the properties is `.Name` - the value of the calculated property. you can get the entire `123` group by `$GroupedAllNames.Where({$_.Name -eq '123'}).Group`. any number of groups can be in the collection of groups ... it's an array of `GroupInfo` objects. it's a _really_ useful structure. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Treating your input as a Json object (from a here string)
The script

- builds akey from the first 3 `-`/dash delimited parts with Select-Object and
  calculated properties.
- Groups by this key
- rebuilds Json objects from the group values.

---

```
$Json = @"
[
"org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail-123-Email",
"org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"
]
"@ | ConvertFrom-JSon

$Json | Select-Object @{n='key';E={($_ -split '-')[0..2] -join '-'}},
                      @{n='value';e={$_}} |
    Group-Object key | ForEach-Object{
        $_.Group.Value | ConvertTo-Json
    }
```

Has this output:

```
[
    "org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
    "org-dummyemail-123-Email",
    "org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
    "org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
    "org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo"
]
[
    "org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
    "org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
    "org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
    "org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
    "org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with the $PSItem variable

```
$arr="org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail-123-Email",
"org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"

$arr2 = $arr | Where-Object {$PSItem -match 'joemarmoto'}
$arr3 = $arr | Where-Object {$PSItem -match '123'}
```

Have a look here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/04/15/working-with-the-new-psitem-automatic-variable-in-windows-powershell-3-0/

From that site:
Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables -ShowWindow

Type “psitem” in the Find box to highlight all text containing this word:

As we can see, $PSItem is the same as $_. The goal with the introduction of the $PSItem variable is making the code containing the “current object in the pipeline” easier to read and understand.

Answer is almost identical to Gert Jan Kraaijeveld, but with explenation what that $PSItem does and where that info comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using regex to determine which part of the input string to group by:

```powershell
clear-host

'REGEX 1; org-dummyemail-123 vs org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto'

$groupedByAllButLast = @(
"org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail-123-Email",
"org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"
) | Group-Object -Property @{E={$_ -replace '([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)-.*', '$1'}} 

for ([int]$i = 0; $i -lt $groupedByAllButLast.Count; $i++)
{
    Write-Verbose $groupedByAllButLast[$i].Name -Verbose
    $groupedByAllButLast[$i].Group
}

'REGEX 2; 123 vs joemarmoto'
$groupedByTheNameOrEmailBit = @(
"org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail-123-Email",
"org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"
) | Group-Object -Property @{E={$_ -replace '[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)-.*', '$1'}} #all we've changed is the location of the opening bracket in this line 

for ([int]$i = 0; $i -lt $groupedByTheNameOrEmailBit.Count; $i++)
{
    Write-Verbose $groupedByTheNameOrEmailBit[$i].Name -Verbose
    $groupedByTheNameOrEmailBit[$i].Group
}
```

NB: This is basically the same approach as [Lee's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53945247/361842); only instead of using `split` and taking a signle segment, we use regex to capture all those parts of the string which are relevant for our key...  See [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6) for a bit more info on this useful function.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea, but with a hashtable:

```
$json = @'
[
"org-dummyemail-123-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail-123-Email",
"org-dummyemail-123-PAT",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATName",
"org-dummyemail-123-PATValidTo",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-AccountName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-Email",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PAT",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATName",
"org-dummyemail1-joemarmoto-PATValidTo"
]
'@

$a = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$b = @{}

$a | ForEach-Object {
    $b[$_.Split('-')[0..2] -join '-'] += @($_)
}

$b | ConvertTo-Json
```